# Mac OS JarLauncher problem

Tags: java, macos

I am running a jar file on mac os.It generates following error

9/2/09 1:17:54 PM [0x0-0x30c30c].com.apple.JarLauncher[11128]  at
content.Main.(Main.java:18)
9/2/09 1:18:06 PM [0x0-0x30d30d].com.apple.JarLauncher[11130]
SystemFlippers: didn't consume all data for long ID 0 (pBase =
0x10012ecc0, p = 0x10012ecc4, pEnd = 0x10012ecc8)
9/2/09 1:18:06 PM [0x0-0x30d30d].com.apple.JarLauncher[11130]
SystemFlippers: didn't consume all data for long ID 0 (pBase =
0x100110140, p = 0x100110144, pEnd = 0x100110148)
9/2/09 1:18:06 PM [0x0-0x30d30d].com.apple.JarLauncher[11130]
SystemFlippers: didn't consume all data for long ID 0 (pBase =
0x100110140, p = 0x100110144, pEnd = 0x100110148)
9/2/09 1:18:06 PM [0x0-0x30d30d].com.apple.JarLauncher[11130]
Exception in thread "main"
9/2/09 1:18:06 PM [0x0-0x30d30d].com.apple.JarLauncher[11130]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/swing/GroupLayout$Group
9/2/09 1:18:06 PM [0x0-0x30d30d].com.apple.JarLauncher[11130]  at
content.Main.(Main.java:18)

Are there required java  libraries i need on my mac ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GroupLayout is introduced in java 1.6 , mac os 10.4 ,10.5 still uses java 1.5 by default. Even when 1.6 is installed you have to manually set os x to use 1.6. Or if you are the developer of the application, there are separate jars for GroupLayout. you can bundle that with your application and use GroupLayout with java 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

Strange error.

From this line it looks like you are missing Swing:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/swing/GroupLayout$Group
```

It may be the case you are using gcj? Try downloading the latest version of Java and see if that improves things.

you can check which version you are currently using with:

```
java -version
```